# Is it possible to create firestore rules based on specific fields?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm going to try to generalise a bit here to make the question simpler. I have a Firestore database that stores users and forum posts. I'm trying to write the rules for the forum posts specifically.

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null
    }
    function isOwner(userID) {
        return request.auth.uid == userID
    }

// ...
    match /forum/{topicID} {
        allow read: if true
        allow create: if isSignedIn()
        allow update, delete: if isSignedIn()
    }
}
```

So here, I've got it so that you can create, update and delete if you are signed in. I also need to add the check, "Do they own this post?", with the `isOwner()` function.

That's all chill, but my problem is - each forum post (AKA topic) has two fields in them that can be updated by anybody who is signed in. These fields are `likes` and `likeCount`.

`likes` is an array of strings, each string is a user's id. `likeCount` is a number equal to the `likes` array length.

I'm starting to see that this would have been easier if `likes` was a sub-collection and `likeCount` could just be `likesSnapshot.docs.length`. I just fear the amount of recoding that might involve!

So, long story short, I want to do something along the lines of:

```
match /forum/{topicID} {
    allow read: if true
    allow create: if isSignedIn()
    allow update, delete: if isSignedIn() && isOwner(resource.data.user.id)
    match /likes && /likeCount {
        allow create, update: if isSignedIn()
        allow delete: if isSignedIn() && isOwner([THE USER ID THAT IS BEING REMOVED FROM THE ARRAY])
    }
}
```

...but I'm not sure of the best way to go about it!

Pleases and thank yous in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to target specific fields like you are showing in security rules.  You can only match whole documents with a `match` statement.

If you want make sure certain users can only modify certain fields, you can use the [MapDiff api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) to check that only those fields are being changed in the document data.  It will go something like this:

```
if isSignedIn() &&
  request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["likes", "likeCount"])
```

This will evaluate `true` if only likes and likesCount are being modified, and the user is signed in.

Comment: Awesome! That is such a useful set of functions to know! Would this rule allow somebody who is signed in to ONLY change the `likeCount`?

Comment: That's what the answer is saying.

Comment: Thanks! Just checking that I could also use it to stop users from giving themselves admin privileges by doing the same and including all the fields except `isAdmin`!

Comment: Perhaps.  If you have a split between public and private data for some entity, it's typically a lot easier to split those up into different collections that have different rules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. I actually did it recently in my own forum.

The way to do it is to allow update if isOwner and restrict what non owners are able to update. You can do that like this:

```
allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
   && request.resource.data.{some field} == resource.data.{some field}
   && request.resource.data.title.{some other field} == resource.data.{some other field}
```

Put all data fields that you don't want non owners to be able to update in the {some field} placeholder. The rule is checking that certain fields have not changed and thus restricting what a user is allowed to change in a document.

Then allow owners full update privs:

```
allow update: if isOwner()
```